# How to programatically tell if Google Drive finished syncing

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to capture an event signifying that google drive has finished syncing.  I was hoping to find a hook into the google drive desktop application, but it seems that isn't possible.

Platform = Windows Server 2008
If custom code required (i.e. not a downloadable application) - ideal language is c# though open to other solutions.

One point of confusion for me
 - The Google Drive web api allows for file manipulation, but I couldn't find anything regarding a full 'sync' feature.  Did I miss that? Or does it just not exist.